# How to store varbinary(max) and varchar(max) data in SQL Server when length is not known (using C++ ODBC)

Tags: c++, sql-server, large-data, odbc

How to store the `varbinary(max)` and `varchar(max)` columns using C++ ODBC API's. Any advice here?

I am using SQL Server native client.

I am **binding Arrays of Parameters using column wise binding**. The aim here is to prepare the statement once and insert/update multiple rows at a time to improve the performance. I got a sample code from this link for this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-arrays-of-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15

Also found this link, where use of SQLPutData is given.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlputdata-function?view=sql-server-ver15
but in this link the example is given using **SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC** i.e. **length of column is known at compile time**. **What should be the solution when the data length is not known before or for same column the data length changes for every row**. **How should we bind such columns in such case?**

I tried passing **SQL_SS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED** as **columnsize parameter** to **SQLBindPatameter** but this does not even compile.

I also tried passing 0 as columnSize parameter to SQLBindParameter hoping it will somehow work but this also does not work.

I have a table called "Parts" which has 5 columns out of that 2 are `varchar(MAX)` and I am trying to insert 3 rows. Below is my code for the same. I have **TEXTSIZE defined as 12000**. As my sample application data length will not cross 12000 I use this value as time being. But in real application data can be bigger than this.

Sample application code

```
SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 5, 0,
        PartIDArray, 0, PartIDIndArray);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, DESC_LEN - 1, 0,
        DescArray, DESC_LEN, DescLenOrIndArray);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 7, 0,
        PriceArray, 0, PriceIndArray);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, TEXTSIZE, 0,
        (VOID *)4, 0, cbTextSize);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt1, 5, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, TEXTSIZE, 0,
        (VOID *)5, 0, cbTextSize1);

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        //GetNewValues(&PartIDArray[i], DescArray[i], &PriceArray[i]);
        std::cout << "Enter the value for PartID(integer)" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> PartIDArray[i];
        std::cout<< std::endl;

        std::cout << "Enter the value for description(string)" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> DescArray[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Enter the value for price(integer)" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> PriceArray[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;

        PartIDIndArray[i] = 0;
        DescLenOrIndArray[i] = SQL_NTS;
        PriceIndArray[i] = 0;

        cbTextSize[i] = SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC;
        cbTextSize1[i] = SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC;
    }

    retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt1, (SQLCHAR*)TEXT("INSERT INTO Parts (PartID, Description,  Price, memo, memo1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"), SQL_NTS);
    // Execute the statement.  
    retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt1);
    if ((retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retcode != SQL_NEED_DATA) && (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)) {
        printf("SQLExecDirect Failed\n\n");
        Cleanup();
        return(9);
    }
    PTR pParmID;
    int index1 = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            index1++;

        retcode = SQLParamData(hstmt1, &pParmID);
        size_t index = ((size_t)pParmID) - 4;
         char* data = Data[index][index1];
         lbytes = strlen(data);
        if (retcode == SQL_NEED_DATA) {
            while (lbytes > 256) {
                retcode = SQLPutData(hstmt1, (SQLPOINTER)data, 256);
                lbytes -= 256;
            }
            // Put final batch.  
            retcode = SQLPutData(hstmt1, (SQLPOINTER)data, lbytes);
        }

        if ((retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)) {
            printf("SQLParamData Failed\n\n");
            Cleanup();
            return(9);
        }
    }


    // Make final SQLParamData call.  
    retcode = SQLParamData(hstmt1, &pParmID);
    if ((retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)) {
        printf("Final SQLParamData Failed\n\n");
        Cleanup();
        return(9);
    }
```

Please let me know if we have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, I have dynamically queried that information from the datasource using the `SQLDescribeParam Function`.

And, if I remember right, if you want to only transfer binary values you are interested in the `Transfer Octet Length`, while if you want to get the result as a string, you probably want to get the `Display Size`.

Sorry I dont remember the details, but I'm pretty sure the entry point about getting the required size dynamically is on those pages here:

- SQLDescribeParam: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribeparam-function?view=sql-server-ver15
- Column Size, Decimal Digits, Transfer Octet Length, and Display Size: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/column-size-decimal-digits-transfer-octet-length-and-display-size?view=sql-server-ver15

Take care what the driver returns as result code - some databases / drivers do not support calculating those values in advance, so you will need to test for every database / driver you want to support.
Good luck

Comment: Hi @erg thank you for your reply. it seems ODBC+Sql server experts are in minority here. I went thru these links but i did not got much help. may be i am missing anything or not understanding your point. i am using native client driver. Also i would want both varbinary and nvarchar fields to pass. please let me know.